# My wordpress does not detect the page category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a new template for WP. I have created category.php and Wordpress doesn't detect it. (Returns a 404.) Must I add something to the functions?

category.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section id="main">
    <?php if (is_category()) { ?>
    <?php } elseif (is_tag()) { ?>
        <h2>Etiqueta <?php single_tag_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
        <h2>Archivo para <?php the_time('F jS Y'); ?>:</h2>
    <?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?><h2>Archivo para <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?>:</h2>
    <?php } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
        <h2>Archivo para <?php the_time('Y'); ?>:</h2>
    <?php } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
        <h2>Archivo del autor </h2>
    <?php } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
        <h2>Archivos del blog</h2>
    <?php } ?>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar() ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't detect it"? Is that template not being loaded at all? Also, the `is_category` conditional is always going to return true since this is a category template. Right now that if statement is empty.

Comment: when I access a category, Wordpress returns an 404 error.

Comment: The problem isn't with your category template. WordPress would fallback to your archive or index template if it could not find the category template. I would not give you a 404. Check your permalinks settings.

Comment: Ok, that was the problem, the permanlinks. They had a configuration with the day and the name of entry... 

Thanks!